# MySQL Server has gone away at loading

Tags: mysql

I start my mysql server with xampp control panel. It worked all the time. I don´t know what have changed, but now the server is crashing if I wanna connect via a mysql program or connect to my local homepage which sends requests to the mysql server.
This is the error in xampp control panel.

```
12:22:38  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
12:22:38  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:22:38  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:22:38  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:22:38  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:22:38  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
12:22:38  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: The problem seems like you have another app or maybe xampp already using the mysql port. Close everything and try it again. If you have skype or something close that and try....

Comment: already tried that. Could I do anything to know which program is blocking mysql?